Direct sum of complement linear subspaces
I'd like to make sure I understand the difference between direct sums and orthogonal subspaces of an inner product space.
In particular I believe the following statement is not true:

If $U_1, U_2, U_3$ are subspaces of an inner product space $V$ so that $V = U_1 \bigoplus U_2 \bigoplus U_3$, then also $V = U_1^{\perp} \bigoplus U_2^{\perp} \bigoplus U_3^{\perp}$.

I know that this is true for the case of $n=2$ (two subspaces which sum to $V$), but for three I am tempted to say it is not the case because:
$ U_1 \bigoplus U_2 \bigoplus U_3 = (U_1 \bigoplus U_2) \bigoplus U_3 = (U_1 \bigoplus U_2)^{\perp} \bigoplus U_3^{\perp}$
and then, for example, if $U_i$ are orthogonal subspaces then $(U_1 \bigoplus U_2)^{\perp} = U_3$ which is not the same as $U_1^{\perp} \bigoplus U_2^{\perp}$.
Is this right?

Or take an example: $V$ is 3 dimensional ip vs, with orthogonal basis $e_1,\ e_2,\ e_3$. Then $e_i^\perp$ are each $2$ dimensional, so the dimension count does us in.

Furthermore, $(U_1+ U_2)^\perp = U_1^\perp \cap U_2^\perp$.

Right. As peter says, this is clearly false most of the time by counting dimensions, also. Conceptually, the $n = 2$ case is sort of a coincidence; what is true in general is that the relationship between subspaces and their complements is inclusion-reversing, so e.g. we have $(U_1 + U_2)^{\perp} = U_1^{\perp} \cap U_2^{\perp}$ as also mentioned by peter (check that this statement is not ruled out by dimension count!), so the "categorical dual" of the statement that $V = U_1 \oplus \dots \oplus U_n$ is actually the statement that
$$U_1^{\perp} \cap \dots \cap U_n^{\perp} = 0.$$
A nice example here is if each $\dim U_i = 1$, so that $V = U_1 \oplus \dots \oplus U_n$ expresses $V$ as an orthogonal direct sum of lines, then the dual statement says that the intersection of the corresponding orthogonal hyperplanes is zero.
Now for $n = 2$ it happens that $U_1^{\perp} \cap U_2^{\perp} = 0$ is equivalent to the statement that $U_1^{\perp} + U_2^{\perp}$ is a direct sum, and then (in the finite-dimensional case!) a dimension count implies that $V = U_1^{\perp} \oplus U_2^{\perp}$. Alternatively, for $n = 2$ we just have $U_1^{\perp} = U_2$ and vice versa. But we don't get either of these for any $n \ge 3$.

(+1) What about the infinite-dimensional case for $n=2$?

@AnneBauval Assuming we are working in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, that depends on what you meant by a direct sum. If it’s an orthogonal direct sum, then of course. In that case we just have $U_1^\perp = U_2$ and vice versa, as Qiaochu already mentioned in the answer above. If the direct sum is purely algebraic, then no. You can choose $U_1$ to be a dense co-dimension $1$ subspace and $U_2$ to be the span of some $x \in V \setminus U_1$. Then $U_1^\perp = 0$, so $U_1^\perp \oplus U_2^\perp = {x}^\perp \neq V$…

@AnneBauval The interesting case is when the direct sum is as Banach spaces, i.e., both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are closed but may not be orthogonal. In that case the result is true. Note that the orthogonal projection $P_{U_2^\perp}$ onto $U_2^\perp$ restricts to an isomorphism $\pi: U_1 \to U_2^\perp$. Indeed, $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$ easily implies $\pi$ is injective. For surjectivity, let $x \in U_2^\perp$. Then $x = u + v$ for some $u \in U_1$, $v \in U_2$, and $x = P_{U_2^\perp}(x) = P_{U_2^\perp}(u + v) = \pi(u)$. So by open mapping theorem, $\pi$ is an isomorphism…

@AnneBauval The adjoint of $\pi$ is then also an isomorphism, but one easily sees that it is just $P_{U_1}$ restricted to $U_2^\perp$, or, to put it another way, $P_{U_1}$ restricts to an isomorphism $\phi: U_2^\perp \to U_1$. Then $\pi \circ \phi$ is an automorphism of $U_2^\perp$, so it has an inverse $\psi$. Now let $Q = \psi \circ \pi \circ P_{U_1}: V \to U_2^\perp$. It is easy to verify that $Q$ is a projection onto $U_2^\perp$ whose kernel is exactly $U_1^\perp$, so $V = U_1^\perp \oplus U_2^\perp$.
